# Groovy script stuck on "Resolving dependency"

Tags: http, groovy, dependencies, groovy-grape

I'm trying to run a simple groovy script for HTTP requests.

Using this dependecy:

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.7.1')
```

Running from command line with this:

```
groovy -Dgroovy.grape.report.downloads=true script.groovy
```

I get this output:

```
Resolving dependency: org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.7.1 {default=[default]}
```

And nothing else.

Groovy version:

```
Groovy Version: 2.3.6 JVM: 1.7.0_80 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Comment: Have you tried to download the dependency using stand-alone grapes as outlined here: http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html (`grape install <groupId> <artifactId> [<version>]`)

Comment: Another thing to try is deleting that directory from your grapes. It may have downloaded one artifact (like the pom), but not anything else (I seem to recall that happening when my downloads appeared stuck). If it keeps happening after cleaning then maybe something else is going on.

Comment: grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder

Also hangs up on my side.

Comment: I am having an identical issue. Did you get resolution?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Unfortunately, I didn't. Last year I wrote another groovy script with http package and grab, but didn't have any troubles. Using newer versions of groovy, http-builder, java and also newer distro of ubuntu. So, no idea what was causing it. :(